# How can i use Select SUM in the column? PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, select, codeigniter-3

Is it possible if i will sum and group by my table? instead of putting it in the variable i want it to display in the fetch data table

my table is something like this

| name | qty | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| milktea | 50 | december 3 2022 |
| milktea | 100 | december 1 2022 |

and when i use this query in the phpmyadmin

```
SELECT product_name, SUM(case when qty>0 then qty else 0 end) as total_stocks
FROM product_inventory GROUP BY product_name;
```

it works though but when i add it into my program to the contoller and models i start to received an error of data table fetch i'm using code igniter here is my code:

controller:

```
public function fetchProductData1()
    {
        if(!in_array('viewProduct', $this->permission)) {
            redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');

        }
        
        $result = array('data' => array());

        $data = $this->model_productstock->getProductData1();
        
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
           

            $availability = ($value['active'] == 1) ? '<span class="label label-success">Active</span>' : '<span class="label label-danger">Inactive</span>';

            $result['data'][$key] = array(
                $value['product_name'],
                $value['qty'],
                $availability,

            );
        } // /foreach

        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

and in models:

```
public function getProductData1($id = null)
    {
        if($id) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM product_inventory where id = ?";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($id));
            return $query->row_array();
        }   
        
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
        if($user_id == 1) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM product_inventory WHERE qty > 0  GROUP BY product_name ORDER BY id ASC";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            return $query->result_array(); 
            
        }
        else {
            $user_data = $this->model_users->getUserData($user_id);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM product_inventory WHERE qty > 0 GROUP BY product_name ORDER BY id ASC";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);

            $data = array();

            return $data;       
        }
    }
```

as you can see i tired the group by and it's working but whenever i add the select sum it start to datatable fetch error i want my output to be:

| name | qty |
| --- | --- |
| milktea | 150 |

here is when i print the $result: here is the response

```
{"data":[["REG Okinawa","10","<span class=\"label label-success\">Active<\/span>"],["Tapsilog","45","<span class=\"label label-success\">Active<\/span>"]]}Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => REG Okinawa
                    [1] => 10
                    [2] => <span class="label label-success">Active</span>
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Tapsilog
                    [1] => 45
                    [2] => <span class="label label-success">Active</span>
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Why not simply `SUM(qty)` ? or is there any negative?

Comment: @MarkusZeller i also tried SUM(qty) but sadly it's still the same and yeah there was a negative number whenever i process a sales

Comment: "i start to received an error" - what does that mean? Can you share the error message, along with your attempts to resolve it?

Comment: @NicoHaase pardon i'm new to codeigniter i'm receiving this message though `"DataTables warning: table id=manageTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1"`

Comment: but without the SUM it's just fine the select and group by works

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. "Invalid JSON response" does not look related to DataTables at all. What does that response contain? Please don't guess, please don't describe, but check it properly